# Regex of email works with decimal value as well. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, regex, django

I have the following two regex patterns.

```
 url(r"^list/(?P<email>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})?/?", MyFunction_ListAPIView.as_view()),
 url(r"^list/(?P<id>[\d+])/$", OtherFunction_ListAPIView.as_view()),
```

I wanted to have two separate functions for email and for id.
If an email is passed `MyFunction` should be called however if a decimal value is passed then `OtherFunction` should be called.

I just passed in a decimal value like so - Here 11 is a decimal value and not regex. Yet it is still calling the same function. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/job/list/11/
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove second to last question mark in the first pattern?

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: No it doesnt however my second one doesnt work either. I think thats because it is missing a + at the end.Also the if i remove the second to the last question mark in the first one then not specifying anything fails as well. I want it to work even if there is no email address- So for empty or a valid email it should work

Comment: Also on that second regex the plus should probably be after the square brackets unless you are trying to match a literal plus sign.

Comment: the `.` in the first half of the email regex is a wild card and not a dot but that won't solve the issue

Comment: What about adding a $ sign to end of email regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?/?` at the end of the first regex makes the email optional. I don't know what you have in the urls list, but I suggest you try your regex here https://regex101.com/ so you can debug easily any url.

Comment: i know it makes it optional however why does an 11 get passed through when i explicitly mentioned that it needs to be an email address ?

Comment: @MistyD - Its because the whole end of the line of the regex is optional so all it needs to match is `list/` which it will match